# How can I resolve a Conda environment for Linux with recent tensorflow-gpu on macOS?

Tags: conda, conda-forge

I want to resolve a Conda environment for Linux with a TensorFlow 2.11 GPU build on macOS. I'm trying to use the [conda-forge TensorFlow packages](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow). With older TensorFlow versions, resolving the environment works.

To resolve an environment for Linux, I set `CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64`. To allow GPU builds of packages, I'm also setting `CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2"`.

This command with TensorFlow 2.11.1 fails on macOS with conda 23.3.0 but works on Linux in a Docker container:

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2" \
conda create -n test -c conda-forge "tensorflow=2.11.1=cuda*" --dry-run

...
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==11.2=0
  - tensorflow==2.11.1[build=cuda*] -> __cuda
  - tensorflow==2.11.1[build=cuda*] -> tensorflow-base==2.11.1=cuda112py39h0320e7d_0 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 11.2
```

This command with an older TensorFlow version succeeds:

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2" \
conda create -n test -c conda-forge "tensorflow=2.9.1=cuda*" --dry-run
```

I suspect the environment with TensorFlow 2.9.1 is able to be resolved because there are [CUDA 10.2 builds available on conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files?version=2.9.1) while for TensorFlow 2.11.1, [only CUDA 11.2 builds are available](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files?version=2.11.1).

However, since I'm specifying `CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2"`, I would expect CUDA 11.2 builds to be included in the resolved environment.

Is there something else I need to configure to resolve this environment on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I tried again a couple of months later with **Conda 23.9.0**, the problem is fixed by adding `CONDA_OVERRIDE_GLIBC=2.17` to the environment:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2" CONDA_OVERRIDE_GLIBC="2.17" \
conda create -n test -c conda-forge "tensorflow=2.11.1=cuda*" --dry-run
```